# How do I read the input text in a line by line manner till EOF in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to read a text from the input in a line by line manner, and not read any line that starts with 'a', then store the remaining text in an array. I am not sure how to do this since my program terminates reading just the first line of the text. Lets say the text is:

> hello world \n a hello world \n hello world'

Then my output should be:

> hello world \n hello world

```
char line[1000];
int line_len = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'){   
     line[line_len++] = c;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Surely you are able to detect if an `'a'` was read.  There is not even an attempt in this code to find it.  What specifically is the issue?

Comment: Your code is just for reading one line. You need to put another loop around it that reads the entire input.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps using `getline` might be easier:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t nread;

while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
    if (nread == 0 || line[0] != 'a') {
        printf("Got a valid line: %s", line);
    }
}

free(line);
```

Comment: might want `line[strspn(line, " \t")] != 'a'` to test if the first non-space or tab character is an `a` -- the example text and output looks like it has space there.

Comment: Also, the `nread == 0` test is pointless (it will never be true) as `getline` can never return 0.

Comment: I recommend checking that `line` is not NULL before calling `free` unless your memory allocator does that for you.